# bring a string array from one activity to populate another list view activity

Tags: android, android-intent

hey guys ive been searching for hours and i cant seem to find anything. I want to bring the quote the user favorites into a list view and have it save for them but i cant seem to get it to go to the list view activity! all help is thanked very much!
heres my code:

Looking at public class favorite is where i need help.

```
public class Startme extends Activity {
    Random gen= new Random();
    int num = 0;

    String[] quotes={
            "End of Quotes, hit next",
            "QUOTE2",
            "QUOTE3",
            "QUOTE4",
            "QUOTE5",};


    public void favorite(View F) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Startme.this, Fav.class);
        intent.putExtra("quotes",num);
    }    

    public void next(View N){
        num++;
        if(num == 5)
            num = 0;

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quote);
        text.setText( quotes[num]);

        TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Qn);
        number.setText(""+num);
    }

    public void back(View B){
        if(num==0)
            num=4;
        else
            num--;

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quote);
        text.setText(quotes[num]);

        TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Qn);
        number.setText(""+num);
    }

    public void rand(View G)  {
        num = gen.nextInt(5);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quote);
        text.setText(quotes[num]);
        TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Qn);
        number.setText(""+num); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.startquotes);

        TextView Dark=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Quote); 
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font1.ttf"); 
        Dark.setTypeface(face); 

        num = gen.nextInt(5);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quote);
        text.setText( quotes[num]);

        TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Qn);
        number.setText(""+num);
    }

    public void favs(View F){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Fav.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is the list view class I made with the intents

```
public class Fav extends Activity {
    public ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter;
    public ListView lv;

    String extras2;
    String[] datos = new String[] {extras2};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.faves);   

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
        extras2 = extras.getString("quotes");

        lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
07-18 04:10:30.565: E/AndroidRuntime(7370): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.me.quote/me.me.quote.Fav}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at me.me.quote.Fav.onCreate(Fav.java:34)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-18 04:10:30.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7370):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: It will forceclose when i hit my fav button

Comment: If your app crashes, you ought to post your logcat errors. (I took a guess at what might be happening though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it crashes when you use fav() because you do not pass any extras to receive here:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
extras2 = extras.getString("quotes");
```

Check for nulls, so you don't get Null Pointer Exceptions:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
if(extras != null)
    extras2 = extras.getString("quotes");
```

**Also** `num` is an `int`, not a String:

```
intent.putExtra("quotes count", num);
```

You must read `int`s with:

```
int count = extras.getInt("quotes count", 0);
```

Using `getString("quotes count")` will return null since there is no String with that key, only an integer.

**Finally** you can pass a String[] like so:

```
intent.putExtra("quotes", quotes);
```

And read it with this:

```
String[] quotes = extras.getStringArray("quotes");
```

Hope that helps!

**Addition**

Your String array `datos` has one null entry, it will not automatically update when you change `extras2`, rewrite Fav like this:

```
public class Fav extends Activity {
    public ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter;
    public ListView lv;

    String[] datos;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.faves);   

        // Check if extras is null, depending on implementation may need to check if Intent is null too
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) 
            datos = extras.getStringArray("quotes");
        else {
            Log.w("Fav", "No string array passed, ListView will be empty!");
            datos = new String[] {""};
        }

        lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to use the `putExtra("quotes", quotes)` Intent (that I posted) in the first Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you say but it still crashes when i hit fav :(, ill post my logcat

Comment: @Maddawg I update my answer. `datos` was always null, I explained why.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Im still trying to figure it out. I did all you said. no errors now. when i click to add to favorites it dosnt add the string to the listview. thank you for your help though

Comment: Ok i did get this to work. Thank you very much. However I just created an arraylist for the user to build and passed that to my listview activity